# How to add onClick event on CKEditor iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I am using CKEditor and I want to perform some task on `onClick` event of CKEditor iframe window. i.e editable area of CKEditor.

```
 CKEDITOR.instances['ckEditor'].on('contentDom', function() {
        this.document.on('click', function(event){
             // calling some other function or some logic
         });
    });
```

But, above code only worked the first time I clicked on CKEditor iframe. Why so? After I clicked on other elements of html page and then I clicked back on CKEditor iframe, it did not work any more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try using below code on some default sample. Basically if you have attached `click` event to editor `editable` and you are using `contentDom` event then event handler for `click` should be fired even after switching to source mode and back where actually old iframe is destroyed and completely new one is created.

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {});
editor.on( 'pluginsLoaded', function( event ) {
    editor.on( 'contentDom', function( evt ) {
        editor.editable().attachListener( editor.editable(), 'click', function( e ){
            console.log( 'click' );
        } );
    } );
} );
```

Comment: Script works perfectly. I have just changed editor value with instance of my CKEditor value.